# C#: Optimize conditional within a loop

Tags: c#, for-loop, inline

I have below nested loops:

```
  (...)
  while (some_condition)
  {
    (...)
    MyObject p = new MyObject(i, j); 
    for (int r = -1; r <= 1; r++)
    {
        for (int c = -1; c <= 1; c++)
        {
            // check matrix bounds
            if (p.y + r <= 0 || p.y + r >= bound1 ||
                p.x + c <= 0 || p.x + c >= bound2)
            {
                continue;
            }                
            else if (matrix[p.y + r][p.x + c]=='$') // at this point no IndexOutOfBounds may be raised as it is checked in previous condition
            {
                continue;
            }

            AddItem(r, c);
        }
    }
 }
```

MyObject is a class that has below attirbutes among others:

```
public class MyObject {
      public int x;
      public int y;

      public MyObject(int x, int y)
      {
         this.x = x;
         this.y = y;
      }

      // Other methods ....
}
```

So I am worried about performance, I mean, I don't like conditional within loop as performance may be decreased, so how can I optimize that?

Also I want to make code more readable so I have rewritten it as below:

```
 while (some_condition)
 {
    (...)
    MyObject p = new MyObject(i, j); 
    for (int r = -1; r <= 1; r++)
    {
        for (int c = -1; c <= 1; c++)
        {
            if (!IsOutOfBounds(r, c, p) && !IsDollar(r, c, p))
            {
               AddItem(r, c);
            }
        }
    }
 }

 private bool IsOutOfBounds(int r, int c, MyObject p)
 {
    return (p.y + r <= 0 || p.y + r >= bound1 ||
            p.x + c <= 0 || p.x + c >= bound2);
 }

 private bool IsDollar(int r, int c, MyObject p)
 {
   // matrix is global
   return (matrix[p.y + r][p.x + c]=='$');
 }
```

But now, calling functions within loop also decrease performance, so how to do and inlined functions? Do I have to preceed both functions with [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)] attribute?

Comment: I think code review site would be better for you.

Comment: I would also recommend checking out their [help center](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help) first.

Comment: _"don't like conditional within loop as performance may be decreased"_ but as a consolation, it saves on exceptions.

Comment: @OusmaneDiaw My code had some errors, I have corrected it. See now.

Comment: Why in world do you need to loop on several values for r and c.   if(p.y <= 1) covers ALL the loops for example.

Comment: You don't need bounds check if the matrix is initialized with +2 rows and columns

Comment: @Slai Yes, I need. bound1 represents matrix height and bound2 matrix width and according my real case it can ocurr an index out of bounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method calls and if statements wont really hurt your performance very much, except you either call that method 1000s of times per second or you are on a very old machine, but also the compiler will optimize that much further. So you should focus more on making code like that more readable and search for real bottlenecks if your program is running slow.

But I also have a question regarding your code, it seems like you would never change x and y in your loops, so couldn't you bring the out of bounds and the dollar check outside of your loops.

Comment: I was typed the code with errors, sorry, now I have corrected it. See post again.

Comment: May I ask, how good/old your computer is, that you are worried about performance that much?

Comment: My computer is new but I am very paranoid with these things, and I always try to avoid using conditionals within loops as far as possible if I can.

Comment: That conditionals within a loop that is called 9 times in total will probably cost you a few microseconds, if not less, most likely much less than the other stuff in your loop

Answer (score 1):

Good job making it more readable and for the correct naming of the methods. As the `for` loops are only being executed 3 times, for values -1, 0 and 1, performance doesn't really come into it with as few loop iterations as you have.

Code readability over premature and unnecessary optimisation every time.